# Spring data findFirst5xxxx returns more than just 5

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jpql

I have a repository that has a method:

```
List<SubGroup> findFirst5BySubGroupId(BigInteger groupId, Sort sort);
```

When I call `findFirst5BySubgroupId` it returns more than just 5.

Why is Spring Data doing this???

Here is example of the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface SubGroupRepository extends CrudRepository <SubGroup, BigInteger> 
{
    List<SubGroup> findFirst5BySubGroupId(BigInteger sectorId, Sort sort);
}
```

Comment: Also I am hitting an Oracle DB

Comment: How does the generated SQL look?

Comment: Where is the definition of the query used by this method? Can you post the source code of the method?